# client side validation on custom type property using custom validator

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have a tricky requirement where i have to compare two model properties which are of custom class types. Server side validation is straight forward but achieving client side validation using jquery unobtrusive is not clear . When the mvc renders the html i am not seeing data-val attributes appended

```
public class CommunicationViewModel
{
    public PhoneViewModel MobilePhone { get; set; }

    [ComparePhoneLocalized("CommunicationView.MobilePhone")]
    public PhoneViewModel ConfirmMobilePhoneNumber { get; set; }

    ........
    ........
}

public class PhoneViewModel
{
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Custom validator**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CompareConditionalLocalizedAttribute : CompareAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly object _typeId = new object();
    private const string ErrorMsg = "Rentered mobile number does not match the original";

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    //public MessageManagement.MessageContext MessageContext { get; set; }
    //public MessageCode MessageCode { get; set; }
    public new string OtherProperty { get; set; }


    public CompareConditionalLocalizedAttribute(string otherProperty)
        : base(otherProperty)
    {
        OtherProperty = otherProperty;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        //** This error message will eventually be driven by resource provider factory **//
        return ErrorMsg;


        //var msg = Message.Create(MessageCode, MessageStatusType.Error, FieldName);

        //var messageRepository = ServeContext.Current.ResolveInstance<IMessageRepository>();
        //msg = messageRepository.MapMessage(msg, MessageContext);

        //return msg.MessageText;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext  
    validationContext)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(OtherProperty)) return null;

        var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(OtherProperty);
        var compareTo = (string)otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        if (value == null) return null;
        if (compareTo.Equals(value.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public new IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata 
        metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(FieldName),
            ValidationType = "compareemail"
        };

        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", OtherProperty);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

**JQuery Wire up**

```
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("comparephone", "[otherproperty]", function 
         (options) {
            options.rules["comparephone"] = options.params.otherproperty;
            options.messages["comparephone"] = options.message;
        });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("comparephone", function (value, element, params) {
            var compareTo = $('[name="' + params + '"]').val();
            if (value == compareTo) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: This might help you out. http://blog.andrei.rinea.ro/2013/06/28/building-client-javascript-custom-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-4-using-jquery/

Comment: Your applying the attribute to a property which is complex object, so not sure how you would expect to see `data-val` attributes which are generated by html helpers for primitive properties.

Comment: @StephenMuecke How should implement the validation for this complex type?

Comment: Are you trying to compare that the value of each property of `PhoneViewModel` are the same (`MobilePhone.Area == ConfirmMobilePhoneNumber.Area`, `MobilePhone.Number == ConfirmMobilePhoneNumber.Number` etc)? If so I think that's going to be difficult.